Storybook not working on Electron Angular App
After installing Storybook 8.4.1 on my Angular 18 / Electron 33 app, and running it by ng run angular-electron:storybook I get:
`=> Failed to build the preview
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array`

the .storybook/main.ts is the standard one.
The storybook page is loaded but it never ends spinning.
Same result if removing all add-ons and stories.
Angular.json
  "storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
          "options": {
            "configDir": ".storybook",
            "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build",
            "compodoc": true,
            "compodocArgs": [
              "-e",
              "json",
              "-d",
              "."
            ],
            "port": 6006
          }
        },
        "build-storybook": {
          "builder": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
          "options": {
            "configDir": ".storybook",
            "browserTarget": "angular-electron:build",
            "compodoc": true,
            "compodocArgs": [
              "-e",
              "json",
              "-d",
              "."
            ],
            "outputDir": "dist/storybook/angular-electron"
          }
        }


We would need angular.json content but may be related to this
